# How does the Linux Kernel store hardware TX and RX filter modes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, network-interface, ioctl

I am working on a C program which gets the timestamping information for a given network interface, like my own version of ethtool. My goal is to get the information printed by `$ ethtool -T myNetIf`. Something like:

```
Time stamping parameters for myNetIf:
Capabilities:
    hardware-transmit     (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE)
    software-transmit     (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE)
    hardware-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE)
    software-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE)
    software-system-clock (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE)
    hardware-raw-clock    (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE)
PTP Hardware Clock: 0
Hardware Transmit Timestamp Modes:
    off                   (HWTSTAMP_TX_OFF)
    on                    (HWTSTAMP_TX_ON)
Hardware Receive Filter Modes:
    none                  (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_NONE)
    all                   (HWTSTAMP_FILTER_ALL)
```

Since I don't want to just scrape the command line output, I have figured out that I can use an `ioctl` call to query this information from ethtool and get my flags back as an unsigned integer.

```c
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
struct ethtool_ts_info etsi;
memset(&etsi, 0, sizeof(struct ethtool_ts_info));

etsi.cmd = ETHTOOL_GET_TS_INFO;
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)); // dev is read from stdin
ifr.ifr_data = (void *)&etsi;

ioctl(sock, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr); // sock is an AF_INET socket
```

The `ethtool_ts_info` struct which (I believe) contains the data I want is defined [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2ac2b1665d3fbec6ca709dd6ef3ea05f4a51ee4c/include/uapi/linux/ethtool.h#L1455). Specifically, I grab the `so_timestamping`, `tx_types`, and `rx_filters` fields.

Using the same example interface, the value of `so_timestamping` is `0x5f`, or `0101 1111`. A look at `net_tstamp.h` [confirms](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2ac2b1665d3fbec6ca709dd6ef3ea05f4a51ee4c/include/uapi/linux/net_tstamp.h#L17) that these are the expected flags.

My issue, however, is in interpreting the values of `tx_types` and `rx_filters`. I assumed that the value of `tx_types` would be something like `0x3` (`0011`, where the 3rd bit is HWTSTAMP_TX_ON and the 4th is HWTSTAMP_TX_OFF). Alternatively, since the possible transmit modes are defined in [an enum](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2ac2b1665d3fbec6ca709dd6ef3ea05f4a51ee4c/include/uapi/linux/net_tstamp.h#L98) with 4 values, perhaps the result would be `0100`, where each `int` enum value is 2 bits.

This is not the case. The actual value of `tx_types` is `0x7fdd`. How on Earth am I supposed to get "HW_TX_OFF and ON" from `0x7fdd`? I find the value of `rx_filters` even more confusing. What is `0x664758eb` supposed to mean?

Besides the kernel source code itself, I haven't been able to find much helpful information on this. I think I've done everything right, I just need some help understanding my results.

Comment: You didn't clear the content of your structures before you called the `ioctl()` to fetch data.  Try changing your variable definitions to `struct ifreq ifr{};` and `struct ethtool_ts_info etsi{};` (or otherwise `memset()` them to 0 before you use them) and see if the behavior you're seeing changes.

Comment: @AndyDalton My apologies, I should've been explicit: I was already memsetting them to 0 (`memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));`, ditto for `etsi`). I omitted the memset lines for brevity since I thought my sample code would imply proper initialization. I'll make an edit

Comment: No problem, I just though some of what you were getting back might be coming from undetermined values on the stack.  Since they're not, I don't know why you're seeing the values that you do.

Comment: As I understand **`ethtool`** show correct information, while your code get messy values on the same system. If yes, we skip buggy NIC drivers assumption.
Did you check `ioctl()` retuкn code?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. `ioctl` does not return anything abnormal. I found the issue and it wasn't related to `ioctl` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing: I have reviewed my code and found that I did fail to properly initialize a struct, just not in quite the way I expected. I also didn't provide the full context needed to solve the problem, since I thought I had ruled out the possibility of junk values left over from before allocation.

The sample code I posted is part of a function which fills out a struct I've defined containing the relevant fields of `ethtool_ts_info`.

```c
typedef struct {
    unsigned int soTimestamping;
    unsigned int txTypes;
    unsigned int rxFilters;
} tsCapsFilters_t;
```

The user of the function initializes this struct themselves and the function merely populates it. So expected usage looks like this:

```c
tsCapsFilters_t tsInfo; // struct full of junk
if(getTsInfo(nameOfNetIf, &tsInfo, errMsgBuf, ERR_BUF_SZ) < 0) {
    // handle errors in here
}
printf("%x\n", tsInfo.soTimestamping); // struct filled out by getTsInfo
```

However, the mistake I made was that I forgot to copy `tx_types` and `rx_filters` from the `ethtool_ts_info` struct (internal to my function) to the `tsCapsFilters_t` struct (given to the user). So my program got all the fields just fine, but it only returned the `so_timestamping` capabilities when it was supposed to return all 3 values.

```c
printf("%x\n", tsInfo.soTimestamping); // printed the expected values
printf("%x\n", tsInfo.txTypes); // printed junk
printf("%x\n", tsInfo.rxFilters); // printed junk
```

Like I said, embarrassing. I'll award the bounty and be more careful with my structs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> struct ethtool_ts_info etsi;
> …
>  ifr.ifr_data = (void *)&etsi;

From the [kernel documentation for network timesamping](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt), I understand that the ioctl(SIOCSHWTSTAMP) your program calls is supposed to fill some struct of the type `hwtstamp_config`

having `struct hwtstamp_config` being defined as :

```
struct hwtstamp_config {
    int flags;  /* no flags defined right now, must be zero */
    int tx_type;    /* HWTSTAMP_TX_* */
    int rx_filter;  /* HWTSTAMP_FILTER_* */
};
```

> Desired behavior is passed into the kernel and to a specific device by
> calling ioctl(SIOCSHWTSTAMP) with a pointer to a struct ifreq **whose
> ifr_data points to a struct hwtstamp_config** … Any process can read
> the actual configuration by passing this structure to
> ioctl(SIOCGHWTSTAMP) in the same way.

When your program uses the data returned as if it was a `struct ethtool_ts_info` defined as :

```
struct ethtool_ts_info {
    __u32   cmd;
    __u32   so_timestamping;
    __s32   phc_index;
    __u32   tx_types;
    __u32   tx_reserved[3];
    __u32   rx_filters;
    __u32   rx_reserved[3];
};
```

This implying that the value your program would extract beyond the third int (and in particular *tx_types* and *rx_filters* you are interested in) are just, as you reported,… **meaningless**.
The (**configuration** iow not capabilities) values for *tx_types* and *rx_filters* should be fetched at the second and third int respectively starting from ifr.ifr_data address instead.

In the case, configuration values are not what you are looking for then, ioctl-ing(SIOCGHWTSTAMP) is not the appropriate way to go.

Comment: _Note_: you considering `ioctl(SIOCGHWTSTAMP|SIOCSHWTSTAMP)` call which use `struct hwtstamp_config` in `ifr.ifr_data`, but in question `ioctl(SIOCETHTOOL)` used with `struct ethtool_ts_info` in `ifr.ifr_data`.

Comment: @SergA : Errr ??? It does seem you are indeed correct. I must rethink why I went to SIOCSHWTSTAMP instead. I'll remove this answer in case I just cannot find the path. Thanks indeed for noticing.